# Getting the difference between two times stored as VARCHAR

Tags: sql, time, type-conversion

So i'm trying to get the difference in minutes between a start time and a finish time, stored as `1130` or `1415` obviously a simple:

```
SELECT finish_time - start_time FROM table
```

wont be sufficient, what do i need to do to work out the difference correctly, taking into account the fact that this is a 4 digit integer being used to represent 24h time.(admittedly terrible way to store time)

Comment: Do the finish_time and start_time ALWAYS belong to the same day?

Comment: @ericpap yes, its a room booking system and i'm trying to create a fucntion that shows the total time in minutes the room is booked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really weird, this way to store time, yes :) Try this:

```
select ((floor(finish_time/100)*60)+mod(finish_time,floor(finish_time/100)*100))-((floor(start_time/100)*60)+mod(start_time,floor(start_time/100)*100)) from table;
```

This converts the last two digits into minutes and the first ones (or the first one) in hours*60 (aka minutes, too) for substracting.

It only works if (finish_time > start_time). I mean, if someone booked a room from today at 18:00 (recording 1800) until tomorrow at 13:00 (recording 1300) then finish_time is less than start_time. Be careful with this, I don't have enough information about days, just times.

Comment: The bookings can't cross days, they are only on a per day basis, it works a charm, many thanks!